# Surrogate pairs cannot display on form

Tags: vb.net, unicode, surrogate-pairs

I'm trying to design a virtual keyboard with character of any language.
Everything goes fine, except one point: codes beyond 0xFFFF.
I'm using surrogate pairs for codes beyond 0xFFFF, like this:

```
Dim codeH As Integer
Dim codeL As Integer

If thisCode > 65535 Then
    thisCode = (thisCode - &H10000)
    codeH = &HD800 + (thisCode >> 10)
    codeL = &HDC00 + (thisCode And &H3FF)
    Return (ChrW(codeH) + ChrW(codeL))
Else
    Return ChrW(thisCode)
End If
```

But as soon I'm using the result as a string to display on a control (richTextBox, label, button, whatever...), all I get is a square or a blank character.

Of course I tried several fonts, even Arial Unicode MS, but I'm still stuck with my squares...

What am I missing ? Any solution ?

Comment: Great. Now I'm aware about That I'd better ask for a solution rather than an idea, what would be your idea about the solution?

Comment: [FileFormat.Info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F6B2/fontsupport.htm) might be helpful to identify which fonts support the codepoint in question. But, I doubt you find anything other than a fallback font that support every codepoint to the current Unicode specification.

Comment: This, seems to be quite helpful, thanks Tom. I'm afraid you're right, it seems to be hard to find fonts with a good coverage for codepoints beyond 0xFFFF.